# Am I handling these promises correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q

Is there a better way to simply catch all errors here or since there are multiple levels in this promise chain with multiple requests I have no other options?

```
        return RequesterService.get('peakBlockIndex', request)
            .then(function(res) {
                rangeData = res.data;
                rangeData.intervals = [];
                if (!rangeData.intervals || rangeData.intervals <= 0) {
                    return $q.reject({ message: 'Request returned no interval data.' });
                }

                return SiteService.getSite(rangeData.site.id)
                    .then(function(site) {
                        if (!site.zoneId) {
                            return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for zoneId failed for the given site.' });
                        }

                        return getDayAheadData(site.zoneId, start, end)
                            .then(function(data) {
                                return handleBlockRange(rangeData, data[0].data, data[1].data);
                            })
                            .catch(function(err) {
                                return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for cleared & forecasted data failed for the given site.' });
                            })
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for zoneId failed for the given site.' });
                    })
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for block-range data failed.' });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Actually that nesting is unnecessary. Any special reason for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Sirko yes actually I need data obtained from the first request to make the second, and from the second to make the third.

Comment: @ShawnRieger This explains multiple calls, but not the nesting itself. From a quick glance, this could all be on the same nesting level.

Comment: Some other sidenote: In case of an error you currently always return the same error message (the last one). I'm not sure, if this is really your intention.

Comment: @Sirko could you elaborate regarding the nesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick glance you should be able to remove the nesting altogether like follows. Note, that in case of an error, this will always return the message `Request for block-range data failed.` similar to your code. The reason is, that using a `$q.reject()` only skips execution of the promise chain until the next `catch()` handler. As you placed such a handler at the end of your code, all errors will be caught here.

```
return RequesterService.get('peakBlockIndex', request)
      .then(function(res) {
          rangeData = res.data;
          rangeData.intervals = [];
          if (!rangeData.intervals || rangeData.intervals <= 0) {
              return $q.reject({ message: 'Request returned no interval data.' });
          }

          return SiteService.getSite(rangeData.site.id)
      })
      .then(function(site) {
          if (!site.zoneId) {
              return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for zoneId failed for the given site.' });
          }

          return getDayAheadData(site.zoneId, start, end);
      })
      .then(function(data) {
          return handleBlockRange(rangeData, data[0].data, data[1].data);
      })
      .catch(function(err){
          return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for block-range data failed.' });
      });
```

Using the newer `async`/`await` syntax, one can improve the readability. This time the actually matching error message is returned. (Note, that one could also return the specific error messages using the upper syntax).

```
async function someRequest( request ){

  let res;
  try{
    res = await RequesterService.get('peakBlockIndex', request);
  } catch(e){
    return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for block-range data failed.' });
  }

  rangeData = res.data;
  rangeData.intervals = [];
  if (!rangeData.intervals || rangeData.intervals <= 0) {
    return $q.reject({ message: 'Request returned no interval data.' });
  }

  let site;
  try {
    site = await SiteService.getSite(rangeData.site.id);
  } catch(e) {
    return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for zoneId failed for the given site.' });
  }

  if (!site.zoneId) {
    return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for zoneId failed for the given site.' });
  }

  let data;
  try{ 
    data = getDayAheadData(site.zoneId, start, end);
  } catch(e){
    return $q.reject({ message: 'Request for cleared & forecasted data failed for the given site.' });
  }

  return handleBlockRange(rangeData, data[0].data, data[1].data);

}
```

Comment: Yes, I totally understand now. Thanks for this great example. Still wrapping my head around promises but this really helps.